# Cannot assign value of type '[String]' to type '[[String : Any]]'

Tags: arrays, swift, string, dictionary, filter

**Swift Xcode version 13.2.1**

Here we have two Arrays,**(1)var dicSearch=String** and  **(2)var searchingDic: [[String: Any]]=[]** I want to assign **searchingDic** to **dicSearch** when i implement it than it show **error** like, **Cannot assign value of type '[String]' to type '[[String : Any]]'**
here's my code, please anyone help!

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        searchingDic = dicSearch.filter{filtering in
            let filterService = filtering["fName"] as? String
            return((filterService?.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()))!)
        }
```

Comment: As it clearly says: You can not put a `string` in storage that needs **pair** of `key:value`s!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to create a filtered list based on a search term, but your `dicSearch` type is an array of `string`s (i.e: `[String]`), while your  `searchingDic` is an array of dictionaries (i.e: `[[String : Any]]`).

This might be confusing when coming from a different language, but in Swift, the following declaration is a dictionary:

```swift
var dict: [String: Any] = [
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
]
```

so the following:

```swift
var arrayOfdicts: [[String: Any]] = [
  ["foo": "bar"],
  ["apples": "oranges"],
  dict
]
```

is actually an array, containing a list of dictionaries, notice how I've put the dict declared above in the second array.

The compiler is telling you that you cannot assign a `'[String]' to type '[[String : Any]]'`

because this:

```
// example to an array of strings 
var fullList: [String] = [
    "apples",
    "bananas",
    "cucumbers"
]

// is not the same as 
var arrayOfdicts: [[String: Any]] = [
  ["foo": "bar"],
  ["apples": "oranges"],
  dict
]
```

The `Array#filter` method, iterates the array itself, and returns a new array with only the elements that return `true` in the return statement.

so either both your arrays need to be `[String]` or both your arrays need to be `[[String:Any]]`

example for String arrays:

```swift
// array
var fullList: [String] = [
    "apples",
    "bananas",
    "cucumbers"
]


var filteredList: [String] = []


var searchTerm = "b"

filteredList = fullList.filter{ item in
  let value = item
  return value.lowercased().contains(searchTerm)
}

print(filteredList) // prints ["bananas", "cucumbers"]
```

an example for filtering with array of dictionaries:

```swift
var people: [[String: Any]] = [
    ["name": "Joe"],
    ["name": "Sam"],
    ["name": "Natalie"],
    ["name": "Eve"]
]


var filteredPeople: [[String: Any]] = []

var nameFilter = "a"

filteredPeople = people.filter{ item in
  let value = item["name"] as! String
  return value.lowercased().contains(nameFilter)
}

print(filteredPeople) // prints [["name": "Sam"], ["name": "Natalie"]]
```

Hope this helps :)